# letterSpacing attribute not working in styles on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, letter-spacing

I'd like to add letter spacing on my collapsingToolbar's title by adding android:letterSpacing=20 in:

```
<style name="CollapsedAppBar" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
<item name="android:letterSpacing">20</item>
<item name="android:textSize">90sp</item>
</style>
```

I'm calling my styles.xml from my activity class:

```
collapsingToolbar.setCollapsedTitleTextAppearance(R.style.CollapsedAppBar);
```

However, the textSize works but the letterSpacing attribute doesn't work, anyone can you help me about this?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like it does not support letter spacing :( `CollapsingToolbarLayout` delegates to `CollapsingTextHelper` which does not look for the `android:letterSpacing` attribute when parsing the `TextAppearance`:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingTextHelper.java#197

Please can you [file a bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Support%20Library%20bug).